# FQDN does not resolve from Windows, hostname does (NMBD)

Tags: networking, samba, dns, hostname

I am trying to configure an Ubuntu Server (14.04) in a Windows AD environment. It will be serving some intranet pages. The goal is to reach this machine by either its hostname (e.g. **ubuntu-server**) or its internal "FQDN" (not sure if that term is appropriate for local domains), let's say: **ubuntu-server.example.domain**.

Relevant files:

/etc/hostname

```
ubuntu-server
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-server.example.domain ubuntu-server
10.0.0.2        ubuntu-server.example.domain ubuntu-server
```

And I installed samba just to enable Netbios on this machine. I am able to resolve the hostname after installing samba, but the FQDN (ubuntu-server.example.domain) does not resolve. The Ubuntu machine is set up with statis IP configuration. The domain is set as a search domain, so the reverse (resolve Windows machines from Ubuntu by FQDN) works fine.

The hostname commands outputs as follows:

```
hostname    : ubuntu-server
hostname -d : example.domain
hostname -f : ubuntu-server.example.domain
```

Did I make any mistakes in my configuration? Anything else I need to do? The goal is to resolve the machine from Windows computers by its local FQDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i have this right you want to use a ubuntu machine as a webserver and have a domain controller your clients connect to for your AD and DNS services, based on this assumtion:

On your domain controller you can create DNS records like *myintranetsitename.mydomain.example* which points to the webserver IP address , any client from that point on using the domain controller as its DNS server when it tries to access *myintranetsitename.mydomain.example* will have its request forwarded to your webservers.

You will also need to configure your webserver to listen on the address *myintranetsitename.mydomain.example*

Please leave a comment if this isn't what you meant or require more info!

Comment: Dan, Thanks for the answer. Yes, I think you got the gist of what I'm trying to achieve. Would you be able to tell me whether the rest of my config, as shown above in the questions, is correct? It seems to me the only piece missing at this point is the DNS entry on the Domain Controller. Is that correct? If so, I will have our IT folks add that entry and should be good to go.

Comment: You will need to edit your webservers config file to listen for _myintranetsitename.mydomain.example_ not your hosts file in ubuntu.

Comment: No worries, feel free to write back with any problems and ill try to modify my answer to suit!